# What Is The Most Efficient Way In Terms Of Run Time Performance To Initialize Thousands of Objects

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, runtime

I am trying to create thousands of instances of a class, *Tile*.

```
int length=64;
Tile tiles[][]=new Tile[length][length]
for(int y=0;y<length;y++)for(int x=0;x<length;x++)
    try{tiles[x][y]=new Tile(x,y);}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

It takes anywhere between .01 to .1 seconds to create a new tile.

I experimented with creating a thread to this, but it made it slower.

```
tiles=new Tile[length][length];
private static int y,x;
final CountDownLatch end=new CountDownLatch(length*length);
for( y=0;y<tiles.length;y++)for(x=0;x<tiles.length;x++)
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
                int y=new Integer(OutterClass.y),x=new Integer(OutterClass.x);      
            try {
                tiles[x][y]=new Tile(x,y);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                end.countDown();
        }
    }.start();
end.await();
```

Is there to speed this up?

Comment: Creating a thread for *every* Tile is likely inefficient, but you might try using a thread pool to initialize each row in separate threads.

Comment: Just a guess: Are you opening a file in `Tile`'s constructor (it throws a `FileNotFoundException`? If that is so, this is likely a place for optimization. You might be able to lazy-load the file or cache the contents of frequently-used files.

Comment: @kiheru If you are saying to have each thread initialize a row, I already tried that and it wasn't faster than the first way, not using threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, someone suggested to pre-load the files. I tried it and it runs significantly faster.
So here is what I did

1. First, when I ran my program, I loaded every file I would use into a
   hashmap. This
       slowed down the loading speed, but it is better than what I had
       before: loading each file when it was needed, which led to reading
       the same file thousands of times.
2. Then, each tile would get the info it needed from the hashmap.

Also, I agree that using separate threads is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on

```
int y=new Integer(OutterClass.y),x=new Integer(OutterClass.x);
```

which is 100x slower than

```
int y = OutterClass.y, x = OutterClass.x;
```

it appears you could optimise the code by taking out the work which doesn't do anything useful.  That would make it faster.

I suggest you use a CPU and memory profiler to see where you are spending most of your time.

If your program is mostly in IO, using more threads will slow down your program. In this case you need to do less IO or buy a faster drive.  Try creating less files.

Comment: that line is needed so that the thread can tell which tile it is suppose to initialize

Comment: But maybe you don't need to create two Integer objects in order to initialize plain old int variables?

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread pool (e.g., a `ThreadPoolExecutor` perhaps obtained via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`). Set the number of threads to something appropriate for your application and execution environment.

Loop over your tiles and `submit` a `Runnable` for each tile. The call to `submit` returns a `Future` - put each of these into a `List<Future<?>`.

Loop over the list of `Future<?>` and call `get()` on each. This step ensure that all of the tasks are completed before you move on.